# Why is my program behaving oddly

Tags: c++

I have just started work on asmall program that sends text over net (TON) I havent quite started but when I compile this happens when I have a space in my name

```
Username: Knight Hawk3
LAN (1) or Net (0):
(Here it wont let me enter data)
Process returned 1 (0x1)   execution time : 3.670 s
Press any key to continue.
```

Here is what normally (should) happen

```
Username: Knight
LAN (1) or Net (0):
1

Process returned 1 (0x1)   execution time : 2.134 s
Press any key to continue.
```

Here is my source

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Headers
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>
#include <SFML/System.hpp>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <SFML/Network.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

bool firstrun = true;

int main()  {

    if (firstrun) {
        cout << "Username: ";
        string name = "";
        cin >> name;
        while (name == "") {
            cout << "Invalid Enter a new name: ";
            cin >> name;
            cout << "\n";
        }
    }
    cout << "LAN (1) or Net (0): ";
    int type;
    cout << "\n";
    cin >> type;
    while (type < 0) {
            cout << "Invalid LAN (1) or Net (0): ";
            cin >> type;
    }

    return true;
}
```

I am running WIN7, Using Code::Blocks

Why is this happening with a space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::cin` reads till the first space but keeps the rest in buffer, which will be used on the following `std::cin`s.

If you want to read till the first `'\n'`(hitting enter) you have to replace `std::cin` with

```
std::getline(std::cin, name);
```

Comment: Thanks, Just one more thing I get the compiler error when I use the getline function http://pastebin.com/rHMhq4zR Here is the source http://pastebin.com/df44MaBr

Comment: @KnightHawk3 You probably did replace the std::cin where you read the int, too. You only have to do that when you read a string which contains a whitespace. For more information on `std::getline` see here http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realise that getline() only took strings!